# How to write custom time format in Microsoft Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, date-time, cell-format

I'm trying to make a format which can convert values like `48.37` to `48h 37m`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that by format alone.  You first need to convert it to a value that Excel will interpret as a time.

Excel stores datetime as days + fractions of a day.
So one method to convert that decimal value to the proper fraction is through an uncommon use of the `DOLLARDE` function.

```
=DOLLARDE(N1/24,60)
```

Then just format the result as `[hh]\h mm\m`

`N1/24` converts the value into fractions of a day.
`DOLLARDE(x, 60)` results in the decimal portion be treated as if the fractional denominator is 60, instead of 100

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want a `48h 37m format`, you have to escape the `h` and `m` characters by putting them in quotes:

format cells / custom format and use:
`hh"h "mm"m"`

so you have two digits for the hours, a `h` with a space, and then the same for the minutes

However, Exel converts hours > 24 to days, so you add brackets:
`[hh]"h "mm"m"`

but if you type in `48.37`, you will get `1160h 52m`, which is 48 days and 0.37th of a day. So you would have to write a formula, to divide by 24, use the integer part for the hours, and the remainder for the minutes.

To go from 48.37 (which are understood as days) to 48 hours and 37 min:
(with the 48.37 in A1)

hours: `FLOOR(A1/24,1/24)` (every full hour is 1/24th of a day)

minutes: `(A1/24-hours)/0.6`  reminder from above, and divide by 0.6 (as there's only 60min in an hour - only works if the decimal part of original value is between 0 and .59)
Then, add the hours and minutes, and format it with `[hh]"h "mm"m"`

To make things easier, just use decimal time. Or count in seconds. Don't write time with a decimal point, when it's not tenths of the unit.